# How to make a folder instantly (as os.makedirs() creates a folder after the program has finished)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to create a folder while my program is still running, because after I create it, I need some files to be put in it.

I've realized that it isn't created instantly and also want to ask why is that happening.

I also get this error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\NemPl\\Desktop\\ProLan\\Python\\Python programi\\user.NemPlayer\\pass.asd123ASD'
```

EDIT:

Here is the source code, which doesn't make my folder appear instantly:

```
import re
import urllib.request
import os.path

print("------PROFILE CREATOR------")
print()
while True:
    breakLoop = 0
    notCorrect = ""
    correct = 0
    profileName = input("Username: ")
    if profileName == "":
        print("Your username can't be blank!")
        continue
    elif os.path.isdir("user." + profileName):
        print("Username taken!")
        continue
    else:
        pass
    for n in profileName:
        if re.search(r" ", profileName):
            notCorrect += "...can't contain spaces!\n"
        if notCorrect == "":
            breakLoop = 1
            break
        else:
            print("Your username...")
            print(notCorrect)
            break
    if breakLoop == 1:
        os.makedirs(r'C:\Users\NemPl\Desktop\ProLan\Python\Python programi\user.' + profileName)
        break
    else:
        pass
while True:
    notCorrect = ""
    breakLoop = 0
    profilePassword = input("Password: ")
    if profilePassword == "":
        print("Your password can't be blank!")
        continue
    else:
        pass
    for n in profilePassword:
        if re.search(r' ', profilePassword):
            notCorrect += "...can't contain spaces!\n"
        if not re.search(r'\d', profilePassword):
            notCorrect += "...has to contain at least one number!\n"
        if not re.search(r'[a-z]', profilePassword):
            notCorrect += "...has to contain at least one lowercase letter!\n"
        if not re.search(r'[A-Z]', profilePassword):
            notCorrect += "...has to contain at least one uppercase letter!\n"
        if notCorrect == "":
            breakLoop = 1
            break
        else:
            print("Your password...")
            print(notCorrect)
            break
    if breakLoop == 1:
        filePassword = open(r"C:\Users\NemPl\Desktop\ProLan\Python\Python programi\user." + profileName + "\pass." + profilePassword)
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: No, `os.makedirs()` creates the folders right when you call it... unless the folder already exists and then you get an error.

Comment: It doesn't work for me for some reason, so I decided to run another python program in a python program which makes the file appear.

Comment: Can you write a simple example fo makedirs not working? It works for me.

Comment: I edited the post. I get the error: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\NemPl\\Desktop\\ProLan\\Python\\Python programi\\user.NemPlayer\\pass.asd123ASD'

Comment: You only made a bunch of directories. You never made a `pass.asd123ASD` file.

Comment: I've never made a pass.asd123ASD file, because the folder wasn't created yet for some reason. And user.NemPlayer folder was the destination of the pass.asd123ASD file.

Comment: Since the file doesn't exist yet, you need to use "w" mode. `filePassword = open(r"C:\Users\NemPl\Desktop\ProLan\Python\Python programi\user." + profileName + "\pass." + profilePassword, "w")`.

Comment: Oh! Thank you! I forgot to put 'w' there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its the "no such file" side of the "No such file or directory" error. You need to include "w" write mode to create the file.

```
filePassword = open(r"C:\Users\NemPl\Desktop\ProLan\Python\Python programi\user." + profileName + "\pass." + profilePassword, "w")
```